# two variables in one text box - flex - actionscript-3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text, variables

quick question.. I'm trying to make two variables appear in one text box but I'm not sure how to do so

Here's what I have.

```
        title1.text = dg_post.selectedItem.post_title;
        date1.text = dg_post.selectedItem.post_date;
```

I'd like to have post_title and post_date appear in the title1 box and remove the date1 box altogether.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust to taste:

```
title1.text = dg_post.selectedItem.post_title + " " + dg_post.selectedItem.post_date;
```